# Sql query refactor from mysql 5.6 to 8.0 (GROUP BY problem)

Tags: mysql

I get error

```
SQL Error (1055): Expression #7 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ifu.amount' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

after migrating to mysql 8.0 from 5.6. I know that it can be easily fixed by disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY flag, but I want it to be more compatible with mysql 8.0. So question is if I would add `ifu.amount` to GROUP BY it should work perfetcly fine and I won't miss any query results or anything? Now without `GROUP BY ifu.amount` MySQL code looks like:

```
select
  `i`.`id` AS `institution_id`,
  `i`.`name` AS `institution_name`,
  `cr`.`check_date` AS `check_date`,
  sum(
    (
      case when (`cr`.`status` = '1') then 1 else 0 end
    )
  ) AS `can_accept`,
  sum(
    (
      case when (`cr`.`status` = '0') then 1 else 0 end
    )
  ) AS `cannot_accept`,(
    sum(
      (
        case when (`cr`.`status` = '1') then 1 else 0 end
      )
    ) + sum(
      (
        case when (`cr`.`status` = '0') then 1 else 0 end
      )
    )
  ) AS `suma`,
  `ifu`.`amount` AS `amount`,
  round(
    (
      (
        (
          (
            sum(
              (
                case when (`cr`.`status` = '1') then 1 else 0 end
              )
            ) * 100
          ) / (
            sum(
              (
                case when (`cr`.`status` = '1') then 1 else 0 end
              )
            ) + sum(
              (
                case when (`cr`.`status` = '0') then 1 else 0 end
              )
            )
          )
        ) * `ifu`.`amount`
      ) * 0.01
    ),
    2
  ) AS `financed_amount`
from
  (
    (
      (
        `check_results` `cr`
        join `family_doctors` `fd` on((`fd`.`id` = `cr`.`doctor_id`))
      )
      join `institutions` `i` on((`i`.`id` = `fd`.`institution_id`))
    )
    join `institutions_funding` `ifu` on((`ifu`.`institution_id` = `i`.`id`))
  )
where
  (`cr`.`status` in (1, 0))
group by
  `i`.`id`,
  `i`.`name`,
  `cr`.`check_date`
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: you can use `ANY_VALUE()` as mysql docs suggests [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

Include `amount` in your `group by` clause.

```
where
  (`cr`.`status` in (1, 0))
group by
  `i`.`id`,
  `i`.`name`,
  `cr`.`check_date`,
  `ifu`.`amount`
```

if `amount` is excluded on your `group by` clause, this will get the `amount` that corresponds on your `id, name and check date` in ascending order (default).

**or**

```
min(`ifu`.`amount`) as `amount`.
```